# Ramining Arrays - If contains "true"

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a for loop which cycles through an array.

```
for(int i = 0; i<=(clientListpost.length -1); i++){
    if(clientpost[i] == true) {
      if((clientpost[i+1] == true) || (clientpost[i+2] == true) || (clientpost[i+3] == true)) {
        clientString[i] = client[i] + ",";
      } else {
        clientString[i] = client[i];
      }
    } 
  }
```

And I check in the second if else if one of the following arrays contains true.

How can I compact the second if condition if I have around 40 following arrays?

I can't use indexOf() because it will always search in all indexes.

**Example:**

My clientListpost => [false, false, false, false] depending on what is seleced on the form (if it's selected => true)

My clientpost genarates 8 arrays for now to make the second if condition work => `if((clientpost[i+1] == true) || (clientpost[i+2] == true)..`
I have done that because if I hit one of the last arrays it gives me the error that the array (5,6,7..) don't exists.

My clientString => ["","","",""] is empty. Because if the clientpost array is false it has a String value.

My client => [1015, 1035, 1040, 1070] gives the values to the clintString Array

At the end I just chain them in row like that:

```
String clientUrl = "";
  for(int i = 0; i<=(clientListpost.length -1); i++){
    clientUrl += clientString[i].toString();
  }
```

**Output:**

if only 1015 is selected => **1015**

if 1030 and 1045 is selected => **1030,1045**

if 1045 and 1070 is selected => **1045,1070**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your ultimate goal by iterating Array?

Comment: wait I write an example.

Comment: The fact that you have 4 different arrays with exact same indexing looks suspicious to me.  Perhaps those should have been objects?

Comment: (clientpost[i+1] ) || (clientpost[i+2]) || (clientpost[i+3]) - this?

Comment: How are you not getting AIOOBE?

Comment: @Andronicus in theory those are different arrays so all of accessed arrays could have at least 3 elements more than `clientListpost` - it is impossible to tell with the provided code.

Comment: I've added an example I hope it's not too confusing, lol

Comment: I still don't see any point in using arrays for this example. And you are binding index from one array with other, this may be troublesome in the future. Secondly you need to check for clientpost.length, in order to not throw any exception. Could you tell in few words what this app should do?

Comment: It is really hard to explain because I work in Flutter and I use Togglebuttons for an user interface. Depending on whats selected I send it to an api via url. And it is pretty hard to do that and this is one solution i found. I compare List<bool> basically to another List<bool>. And binding the indexes together through an for loop  works really well.

Comment: I don't quite get your question and example. Why are you appending commas to individual elements? I'd do that when trying to reduce them into a single string but not when still operating on individual elements. Also why don't you just collect the selected elements into a new array or yet better a list (that could be turned into an array if needed)? Besides adding the comma is there any other need to check whether any subsequent elements are selected?

Comment: I do reduce them into a single string at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make a few assumptions here (please also refer to my questions in the comment to your question):

- you really need to build the arrays like this
- you've made sure no ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is being thrown

Instead of checking whether any subsequent elements have been added, just iterate backwards:

```
boolean subsequentElementsSelected = false;
for(int i = clientListpost.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
  if(clientpost[i]) { //or clientpost[i] == true
    if(subsequentElementsSelected ) { 
      clientString[i] = client[i] + ",";
    } else {
      //only true for the last element to be added/set
      clientString[i] = client[i];
    }

    //once we've added an element at the end this will stay true
    subsequentElementsSelected  = true;
  } 
}
```

From your comment:

> I do reduce them into a single string at the end.

If that `clientString` array isn't needed just append to the string and add commas if needed:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i <= clientListpost.length -1; i++){
  if(clientpost[i]) { //or clientpost[i] == true

    //if there's already something in the String, add a comma first
    if(builder.length() > 0) { 
      builder.append(",");
    } 

    //add the element
    builder.append(client[i]);
  } 
}
clientUrl += builder.toString(); //assumes there's more in clientUrl, otherwise just assign
```

Comment: To your first question: I could have done that, but I don't want it to complicated, which it already is ^^. To your second question: No, only the comma. But your answer looks also good, i will try the second one, and I let you know.

Comment: The second example with the StringBuilder also worked. It is actually better than the other answer because its shorter. But I work in Flutter so the StringBuilder is not available. So I needed to change it a bit.

Comment: I have  one more question: Why does it not append  comma at the last client?

Comment: @Timebreaker900 I've rejected your edit because that's more of a comment as you already did (Flutter doesn't have StringBuilder) and adjusting the example to what's available shouldn't be too hard. I'd also suggest using the second option - I've added the first only because it wasn't clear whether you'd need that intermediate array or not.

Comment: @Timebreaker900 "Why does it not append comma at the last client" - I assume you're refering to the first option but they basically work the same: if a selected element has already been found add a comma in between the new one and those that have already been found and if there isn't one yet just use the new one. The actual difference is (besides using that intermediate array): option 1 _prepends_ new elements while option 2 _appends_ them, i.e. option 1 is like `c` -> `b, c` -> `a, b, c` while option 2 is like `a` -> `a, b` -> `a, b, c`.

Comment: Aaaah, I get it know, it gets append on the next one BEFORE the value. I was always thinking it gets applied AFTER the value... and the `builder.length > 0` basically gets triggert evertime because after the firstone the builder is always bigger then 0 .. omg.. my brain hurts now. Anyway a big THANKS to you, Thomas! :D

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can create an additional method for determining if you need to add comma to `clientString[i]`

```
for(int i = 0; i<=(clientListpost.length -1); i++){
    if(clientpost[i]) {
        clientString[i] = client[i];

        if (isClientPostEnabled(clientListpost,clientListpost.length -1, i)) {
            clientString[i] += ",";
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isClientPostEnabled(List<bool> clientListpost,int index, int startIndex) {
    for (int i = startIndex; i < index - startIndex; i++) {
        if (clientpost[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That' not it. I think your answer always puts an comma at the end of the value if it's selected. But I need it to only put a comma at the end IF an array after the current one is true or am I wrong?

Comment: It puts comma only if `isClientPostEnabled` returns true. The method `isClientPostEnabled` checks if there at least one `true` value starting from `startIndex`. 
If there all remaining values are `false` than `isClientPostEnabled` also returns false. And comma will not be put into clientString

Comment: Oh yeah I it now I will try it!